# I2C: Can you pull up SDA/SCL lines through an LED?

Tags: led, i2c, blink

Everyone likes blinky lights.

Is there any (technical) reason *not* to pull up the SDA/SCL lines through an LED?

Comment: You did not show a schematic, so you already get two answers that interpret what you mean, and I can easily come up with more scenarios. Pull up via LED but without resitors? Or if there are resistors, where?

Comment: @Justme, Oh, of course, the LED needs a resistor anyway...so normal resistor, in series to the LED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can but there are also reasons against it, but they might not be relevant depending on how exactly you will implement it, or it may slow down the bus and cause all kinds of problems.

So I take it you don't mean to just replace the pull-up resistors with a LED. That would not work and make no sense. I assume you either want to pull up each line to supply through a LED and a resistor.

If you simply put a LED in series with the pull-up resistor, and assume you are using a 2V green LED in a 5V system, you need to adjust the resistance to allow the same current when the line is pulled low.

But as there is 2V drop over LED, your pull up voltage is now only 3V, which is usually not enough for a 5V bus. And any overshoots won't get pulled down to supply voltage, because LED only  conducts in forward direction.

This can be mitigated by having a direct pull-ups and then separate LEDs with series resistors, adjusted to provide total current that does not exceed the rated current for the bus or the chips.

But then the problem is that on rising edge, both paths provide current when voltage is low, but after bus voltage is high enough, say 3V, the LED path provides no current and the direct pull-up is weaker than originally so the bus voltage rises slower after the LED is off.

LEDs also have some capacitance, so if you turn on a LED you have also charged the capacitance. That's why the LED will keep 2V over it even with no current flowing because it barely discharges itself. Another reason for a separate resistor to discharge the volage of LED to 0V.

And the, LEDs are also light sensitive devices. They are like photodiodes, just very poor photodiodes compared to actual photodiodes. They have leakage current through them that depends on surrounding light that hits it. They also generate photocurrent like photodiodes, and they generate voltage over them in photovoltaic mode like photodiodes. That effect might not be significant but it basically means your bus waveforms are dependent on surrounding light, so there is noise and extra uncertainties you need to handle.

So if you design and implement it correctly and verify that the LEDs don't cause a problem, then go for it. But with the effort going into designing it, leave the pull-ups alone, add a dual buffer chip, bypass cap, two LEDs and two resistors and it's done with a high impedance input and selecting the chip properly may allow you to monitor a 5V bus with a 3.3V supply for the chips or drive LEDs from higher supply if buffer has open-drain outputs.

Answer (score 1):

SDA/SCL need pullups that will keep supplying current to charge the line capacitance all the way up to the pullup voltage. Resistors do this, LEDs don't. They conduct only a miniscule leakage current at slightly below their nominal voltage.

SDA/SCL also need pullups that can be pulled down by the drivers that are meant to pull them down. Resistors do this, LEDs don't. They conduct a colossal, damaging, current at slightly above their nominal voltage.

So the answer is yes, you can do this. But if you do, your I<sup>2</sup>C link will not work, and you will probably damage the drivers, and/or LEDs.

You could perhaps create a Thevenin source to a higher voltage, and put the LED in series with that. However, that needs a higher voltage power supply and kludgy work, so you would be better off employing logic buffers to sense the voltage on the lines, and use them to drive blinky LEDs in the conventional way.

Answer (score 1):

Alone, no.

You can put an R+LED from +V to each line if you want, as long as R is much larger than the normal pull-up which is still required.  Load current and bus capacitance are increased slightly as a result, of course, and must still be within the capability of all devices on the interface, plus bus resistance.

It's also not clear how much good this would do.  Lights either blink erratically as data is passed around, or in short bursts (a single transaction might not even be visible in a normally-lit room), or continuously at such rate that it hardly seems to flicker.  Depending on what you're doing.  Conversely, something that can see well enough (high speed cameras, photodiodes) might be able to read the data verbatim, a potential vulnerability.

Comment: +1 for the vulnerability point. If I was doing this, I would put such a led on the SCL line only.

Comment: Even that can be a vulnerability, e.g. frequency and correlation attacks on naively made network routers. A missing-pulse detector with start-up and stop delays (preferably randomized) is a better solution; it's more visible as well (when minimum on-time is comparable to persistence of vision (10s ms), and minimum off-time several times more).